# creating new variables with transform and %>%

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I'm trying to use the "pipe-like" operator to create a new variable, the same length as others in the dataframe, based on the `LETTERS` vector. Something is going wrong, and I am too new to `magrittr` to diagnose the problem.

I am able to create the variable correctly when I try with some "traditional" nested functions:

```
expand.grid(a=c(1000-500,1000,1000+500),
                       b=c(15,150)) %>%
  mutate(c=paste("foo", LETTERS[seq_along(a)],sep="_"))

##      a   b     c
## 1  500  15 foo_A
## 2 1000  15 foo_B
## 3 1500  15 foo_C
## 4  500 150 foo_D
## 5 1000 150 foo_E
## 6 1500 150 foo_F
```

So then I thought I'd try with the pipelike `%>%` from `magrittr` and `dplyr`

```
expand.grid(a=c(1000-500,1000,1000+500),
                       b=c(15,150)) %>%
  mutate(c=paste("foo", a %>% 
                   seq_along %>% 
                   LETTERS[.],sep="_"))

## Error: incorrect number of dimensions
```

This also does not work when I add the aliased extract (`[`) function from `magrittr`:

```
expand.grid(a=c(1000-500,1000,1000+500),
                       b=c(15,150)) %>%
  mutate(c=paste("foo", a %>% 
                   seq_along %>% 
                   extract(LETTERS,.),
                 sep="_"))

## Error: incorrect number of dimensions
```

I've tried debugging the pipe with `debug_pipe` to no avail.  I'd be very grateful for any ideas!

Comment: Turns out that `.` was being confused with `.()` from `plyr`.  detached that package and everything worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, if you want:

```
expand.grid(a=1000+c(-500, 0, 500), b=c(15,150)) %>%
mutate(c = a %>% seq_along %>% LETTERS[.] %>% paste0("foo_", .))
```

Comment: so elegant! Do you know if there is any plan to make it less likely to confuse `.` with `.()`?

Comment: I cannot replicate the .() problem. With only plyr and magrittr loaded, both your version and mine works fine.

Answer (score 3):

If we define an auxilliary function `Swap` then  it can be done without using . like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

Swap <- function(f) function(x, y, ...) f(y, x, ...)

expand.grid(a=1000+c(-500, 0, 500), b=c(15,150)) %>%
  mutate(c = a %>% 
             seq_along %>% 
             Swap(extract)(LETTERS) %>% 
             Swap(paste0)("foo_"))
```